# How to row reduce a matrix where we get zeros in the middle

Tags: matrices

How do I row reduce the following matrice? I have seen similar questions but this looks confusing and messy so I gave up.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 7 & 8 \\
    2 & 3 & 4 \\
    5 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Also the zero makes it diffuclt for me to do this (after a few steps).

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to swap rows during the row reduction process.  If you get a row of zeros, simply swap it to the bottom of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract mutliples of upper rows from bottom rows to get your pivots.

$$
    \begin{matrix} 
    1 & 7 & 8 \\
    2 & 3 & 4 \\
    5 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix} 
    1 & 7 & 8 \\
    0 & -11 & -12 \\
    0 & -34 & -37 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix} 
    1 & 7 & 8 \\
    0 & -11 & -12 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{11} \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Without showing your work, I don't know what zeros you are talking about